# Google + (after sign in retrieve the code)

Tags: google-plus

I completed the Google + sign in.But after sign in I want to retrieve the inforamation means User first name and lastname seperately.But I retrieve the full name Using disPlayname.But I want first name and last name seperately. So please help any one.Because those values should be passed to one method in my web application.My web application is based on JAVA.(Ecommerce site).Please suggest any code for me.

Comment: Flagging this question as off-topic because it is unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `displayName` field in the returned object, you can use the `name.firstName` and `name.lastName` fields.

See https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people#resource for details and for what other fields are available as part of `name`.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.Now I got the first name and second name seperatly.How to put the logo after sign in .(Means I want to show my compent logo after google + sign in ).Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is related to your original question. If this answered that question, you might want to accept it. If you have further questions related to it, you might want to expand the original question (and possibly show some example code). If this is a new question - you might want to open it as a new question in StackOverflow and show some example code that illustrates what problems you're having.